# Calling linker function only after the template was parsed

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-directive

I'm creating a directive in AngularJS that uses a bootstrap plugin for "checkbox switch"

I'm initiating the plugin inside the `link` function of the directive, but it seems like the function get called before the `ng-checked` directive is being parsed so I always get unchecked switches

I tried adding a timeout before the initialization of the plugin - and it worked as expected after the delay, which supports my assumption that the problem is the order of execution)

This is my Javascript and HTML:

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp',[])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.files = [
      {name: 'a.txt', valid: true},
      {name: 'b.txt', valid: false},
      {name: 'c.txt', valid: true}
    ];
}).directive('switch', function(){
  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    var cb = $(element).find('input');
    cb.bootstrapSwitch({
      onText: 'Valid',
      offText: 'Error',
      offColor: 'danger',
      onSwitchChange: function(e, val){
        scope.file.valid = val;
        scope.$digest();
      }
    });
  };
    
  return {
    link: link,
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="file.valid" />'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/nostalgiaz/bootstrap-switch/master/dist/css/bootstrap3/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/nostalgiaz/bootstrap-switch/master/dist/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="file in files">
      <span>{{file.name}}</span> The Switch: <switch file="file" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly set the state in your link function using `state: scope.file.valid`. Otherwise you have to use a `timeout`.

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp',[])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.files = [
      {name: 'a.txt', valid: true},
      {name: 'b.txt', valid: false},
      {name: 'c.txt', valid: true}
    ];
}).directive('switch', function(){
  function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    var cb = $(element).find('input');
    cb.bootstrapSwitch({
      onText: 'Valid',
      offText: 'Error',
      offColor: 'danger',
      state: scope.file.valid,
      onSwitchChange: function(e, val){
        scope.file.valid = val;
        scope.$digest();
      }
    });
  };
    
  return {
    link: link,
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="file.valid" />'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/nostalgiaz/bootstrap-switch/master/dist/css/bootstrap3/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/nostalgiaz/bootstrap-switch/master/dist/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="file in files">
      <span>{{file.name}}</span> The Switch: <switch file="file" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, 10x - it's working in my case. but it still sounds weird that there is no solution for that inside Angular.
The solution here is good for my case but might not be suitable for others